# SQL Server doesn't use the index when `LIKE` clause contains a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, ssms

I am trying to optimize a certain query created by Entity Framework, and I have stumbled on a weird execution plan difference in SSMS.

The table is:

```
-- int Id, string Name
CREATE TABLE [Clients]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](550) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Clients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id) ASC
)

-- create index on Name, and include Id desc
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Clients_Name] ON [Clients]
(
    [Name] ASC,
    [Id] DESC
)
```

And I narrowed the issue to the following simple query:

```
DECLARE @filter nvarchar(4000)
SET @filter = N'Johnnie'

-- use the parameter in WHERE clause
-- (this is what EF core basically generates)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Clients
WHERE Name LIKE @filter + N'%'
ORDER BY Id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

-- use hardcoded string clause
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Clients
WHERE Name LIKE N'Johnnie%'
ORDER BY Id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

In case of the first one, actual execution plan shows an index **scan**, followed by Top 10 (and scans all 30000 rows), while the second one does an index **seek**, followed by a Sort (and seeks only the single matching row) -- obviously the second one is preferrable in this case, and in the general case (since I will usually only have a couple matching names).

I updated statistics, but it didn't change (although I don't understand why there would be a difference in the first place).

Could someone give an idea on why is there a difference?

(btw if I remove the `ORDER BY ... OFSET ... FETCH` part, then it uses index seek in both cases)

Comment: Does anything change if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the first query? What about `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@filter = UNKNOWN))` or `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@filter = N'Johnnie'))`? You might just get a bad cached plan, or an overly conservative one based on not knowing the filter value and having very homogeneous data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: thanks! In fact, in some cases this option seems to give different results. So probably the parameterized version is cached, but the second one isn't?

Comment: In the general case `@filter` might start with a wildcard. So it has to produce estimates that take into account the "seek" might have to touch all rows in the table. The values of variables aren't sniffed unless you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so you will get the same plan for `SET @filter = N'Johnnie'` and `SET @filter = N'%'`

Comment: @MartinSmith: aaaah that's right! Do you think this might be the case? I would expect that it at least checks the value of the `@filter` before optimizing (but I obviously don't understand the optimizer at all).

Comment: For a **parameter** it checks the value that happened to be passed when the plan is compiled (so vulnerable to "parameter sniffing" issues if that parameter value was atypica)l. Your repro is using a **variable** though and these are never sniffed except if using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: And just to add that a seek is possible with. a leading wild card but SQL Server then computes a start and end value that covers the entire domain of possible string values in the index so this is effectively a scan of the whole thing, plus need to do lookups for every row in the table

Answer (score 0):

Your data might look like this:

```
Name       ID
John1      300
John3      301
John2      302
```

The index is first ordering by `Name`.  As you can see, the `id`s are not in order.  So, SQL has to sort them.  Or scan the primary key index (it decides which is better).

You can sort by `Name` if you want the index to be used efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how indexes work, but what I don't understand is why is there a difference between specifying a literal (`WHERE Name LIKE N'Johnnie%'`) and using the parameter (`WHERE Name LIKE @filter + N'%'`). These two queries give different execution plans.

Comment: @Lou . . . That is an optimization threshold, which depends on rules and statistics in the table.  If this query is stored (say in a stored procedure), then you might also have a parameter sniffing problem.